# Command like function execution

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JS terminal, and, for executing commands I use the following method:

```
function cmd(command){
    var args = command.split(" ");
    var size = args.filter(function(value) { return value !== undefined }).length;
    if (args[0] === "command-name") {
        ...stuff to do
        return;
    }
    if (args[0] === "another command") {
        ...stuff to do
        return;
    }
}
```

Is there some more efficient/neat way to do that?

Comment: Use a lookup table. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: Try the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to store the command-name to function mapping, something akin to

```
var commands = {
    "command-name": function doCommandName (args) {
        alert("My arguments: " + args);
    },
    "another-command": function doAnotherCommand (args) {
    }
};

function cmd(command) {
    var args = command.split(" ");
    var cmd = args[0];
    if (commands.hasOwnProperty(cmd)) {
        commands[cmd](args.slice(1));
    }
    else {
        alert("Unknown command " + cmd);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can hardly be done in a more elegant way. However, you could use an array of objects, each of which would have a string `name` and some function `execute` as members, and the implementation would select the array member based on `args[0]`.